# How to visualize a Mnesia schema?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Is there any available tool/script to visualize an Erlang Mnesia schema?

Ideally it should generate [.dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) to be read with Graphviz or any other similar piece of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: I haven't heard of anything available.

What would you visualize about the schema? It would be hard to generate a visualization of the relationships between tables because there's no explicit data stored about that. (No schema I've encountered actually uses mnesia's (exotic) foreign_key functionality.)

I can imagine some visualization of the replication layout of the schema (which nodes have which fragments of which copies of which tables), but due to the lack of table inter-relationship information, I don't think there are visualizations available for that.